# How to add random prefix (based on related page slug) to custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want to create some specific url structure for my website. My Pages will be Inner Home pages that will combine articles and reviews.
Articles and reviews are 2 separate custom post types.
I would not like to make them child pages for the Inner Home page and have all the pages in one Pages list. I will create Article CPT and add ACF Field to connect article to some Inner Page
So, I want the CPT URL to look like a child page of some Page (basic post type - 'page'):
website.com/%inner_home_page_slug%/%article_slug%

%inner_home_page_slug% - related (by acf field) page slug

%article_slug% - usual post slug

/article/ cpt base should be removed

Is it possible? (I am aware of the slug conflict, so probably it's ok to leave cpt slug and have structure like %inner_home_page_slug%/article/%article_slug%)

Can anyone help me? I will be eternally grateful

Comment: To clarify:  You want the parent slug to be dynamic based on the value of a custom field?

Comment: @MarcGuay Yes, exactly. I've coped with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

So I've added rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^[^\/]*\/review\/([^\/]*)$',
    'index.php?review=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

And additional code to create appropriate url structure:

```
function rev_update_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'review' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    //** Field where related page post object stored in ACF field **//
    $pageid= get_field('related_home_inner_page',$post->ID);
    
    $post_link = str_replace( '/review/', '/'.$pageid->post_name.'/review/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'rev_update_slug', 10, 3 );
```